# High use of CPU on AWS RDS mysql

Tags: performance, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

I am experiencing trouble with a database, I am pretty sure there are some troublesome queries created by the programmers, but I need to find the culprit. So usually I dont have a problem with the database, but when we get up to a point everything seems to slow down. I am using mysql database in AWS, not aurora. I actived performace insight.
This is how it looks when we are having problems
[image]

This is a closer look at the  biggest bar in the graph:

[image]

So it seems like some queries are locking the table but have troubling finishin and it takes a while to unlock the table right??
This is weird for me when I look at the Top SQL
[image]
Why is use showing like one of the TOP SQL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Posting TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; when experiencing the high load would be most helpful in identifying the querie(s) responsible.